# Generating a Population for Genetic Algorithm in C

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm

I have just learned the basic (more of an introduction) of genetic algorithm. For an assignment, we are to find the value of x that maximizes f(x) = sin (x*pi/ 256) in the interval 0 <= x <= 256.

While I understand how to get the fitness of an individual and how to normalize the fitness, I am a little lost on generating the population. In the text, for the purposes of performing crossover and mutation, represent each individual using 8 bits. Example:

189 = 10111101

35 = 00100011

My questions are this:

1. Using c, what is the best way to generate the population? I have looked it up and all I could find was using uint8_t. I'm thinking of generating it as an array and then find a way to convert to it's integer representation.
2. What purposes does normalizing fitness serves?
3. As this is my first time at writing a program that uses genetic algorithm, is there any advice I should keep in mind?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The initial population should be random.

Comment: "the interval 0 <= x <= 256" excludes the use of `uint8_t` since `256` is out of range. Work with the natural size `int` or `unsigned` unless good reason not to.

Comment: To create the random population, I was thinking of using rand() to generate the random population, covert it into 8 bit representation and then store in an array. The problem is the conversion part.

Comment: `unsigned char individual = (unsigned char)( rand() % 255 );`

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is the population to be random, but if you have some preliminary optimization you can form population around results already available.

It is very common to use hybrid algorithms when GA is mixed with altoritmsh like PSO, simulated annealing  and so on.